# Passing active tab event to parent and sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Tab navigator that handles data changing of itself and other two sibling component.

**Main parent Component** that does data fetching and manipulation based on three sentiments: positive, negative and neutral as request body parameter in *http post request*.

**Second parent component** that stores all positive data, negative data and neutral data from main parent component.

Then **three** **Child Components**: **Table one and Tab Navigation**.

The Tab navigation has three three tabs namely: *Positive, Negative and Neutral*.

As soon as the page renders on first load, by default (without clicking positive tab button), it fetches positive data and displays it in all three child components. Then on clicking on Negative tab, it should display negative data in all three child components i.e. Table one and under negative tab of tab navigation. Same thing follows for Neutral Tab.

In short, Tab navigation handles data rendering of it's self and sibling components based on its active state and getting that data from parent component.

I tried passing the active event from tab navigation to its upper container but it doesn't seem to work fine.

Tab.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Tab extends Component 
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = 
        {   
            active: 'positive',

        }
    }



    toggle = (event) => 
    { 

        this.setState({
          active: event
        })

        this.props.sendEvent(this.state.active);
 }

    get_tab_content =()=>
    {
        switch(this.state.active)
        { 
            case 'positive':
                return <div><SomeDataComponent1 positiveprops={} /></div>; 
            case 'negative':
                return <div><SomeDataComponent2  negativeprops={}/></div>;
            case 'neutral':
                return <div><SomeDataComponent3  neutralprops={} /></div>;
            default : 
        }
    }

  render() {

    const tabStyles = {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        listStyleType: 'none', 
        cursor: 'pointer', 
        width: '100px',
        padding: 5,
        margin: 4,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'green'
      }


    const tabStyles2 = {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        listStyleType: 'none', 
        cursor: 'pointer', 
        width: '100px',
        padding: 5,
        margin: 4,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'red'
      }


      const tabStyles3 = {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        listStyleType: 'none', 
        cursor: 'pointer', 
        width: '100px',
        padding: 5,
        margin: 4,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'yellow'
      }


    const linkStyles = {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      color: '#000',
      listStyleType: 'none'
    }

    const divStyle = {
      border: '1px solid #34baa2',
        width: '450px'
    }

    const box = this.get_tab_content()

    return (
      <div style={divStyle} >
        <ul style={linkStyles}>
          <li style={tabStyles} onClick={function(){this.toggle('positive')}.bind(this)}>Positive</li>
          <li style={tabStyles2} onClick={function(){this.toggle('negative')}.bind(this)}>Negative</li>
          <li style={tabStyles3} onClick={function(){this.toggle('neutral')}.bind(this)}>Neutral</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            {box}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

 }
```

Second Parent Component.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Tab from '../tab/tab';

import MentionTable from '../table/table';


class DataCharts extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        childEvent: ''
    }
}


getEvent = (childevent) => {
    this.setState({
        childEvent: childevent
    });

    console.log(this.state.childEvent)
}


    render(){
        const {positivetable,positivewords,  negativetable,  negativewords, neutraltable, neutralwords } = this.props;


        return(

                <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Table />

                        <Tab sendEvent={this.getEvent}/>
                </div> 

        )
    }
}


export default DataCharts;
```

Comment: Your code works fine, https://codesandbox.io/embed/passing-props-wfg53, edit this sandbox and explain your problem

Comment: @DennisVash Check the console. When I click positive tab, it consoles negative, on negative: neutral and so on. Consoles not printing in the order active tab pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the next lines:

```js
  toggle = event => {
    this.setState({
      active: event
    });

    this.props.sendEvent(this.state.active);
  };
```

`setState` is asynchronous, so you sending to `sendEvent` the not intended state.

```js
  toggle = event => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log('prevState', prevState);
      console.log(event);
      this.props.sendEvent(event);
      return { active: event };
    });
  };
```

[image: Edit Passing Props]

Comment: It works ! :)  Now my  main parent component is already passing all the props(based on positive, negative and neutral request body param) to this second parent component. In second component I need to conditional render: if(active state === positive) { render positive data props from main component further} else if( active state=== negative){ render negative.... } and so on? How can I achieve that?

Comment: I edited the `codesandbox` check this out, it's just one possible pattern for what you asking, please **ask another question** and feel free to send me a link and I'll try to help.

Comment: I tried your approach but got confused in between. Please guide me how can I send you link to review it

Comment: Just ask another question on StackOverflow, post your sandbox and send me the link of the question

Answer (score 1):

I think calling the parent function in `setState` callback would work, for thet we need to do it like this in **Tab.js**

```
this.setState({
          active: event
        }, () => { this.props.sendEvent(this.state.active)})
```

also `console.log(this.state.childEvent)` should be also in callback too so that you get the state after it has been updated, we need to change **DataCharts.js** too

```
this.setState({
              childEvent: childevent
            }, () => { console.log(this.state.childEvent)})


 Working demo -: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zhbmad
```

Comment: Still not solving up